# Is the limit at infinity of an absolute multivariable polynomial always infinity?

Tags: multivariable-calculus

My textbook is asking me to prove that, given $p_n(x,y)$ polynomial of degree $n\geq1$ in $x,y$, it is true that:
$$ lim_{|(x,y)|\rightarrow\infty} |p_n(x,y)| = +\infty $$
But if I take, for example, $p_n$ to be $x^2 - y^2$, then i get that the limit does indeed approach $+\infty$ everywhere except along the lines $y = x$ and $y = -x$ on the $x,y$ plane. I fear I'm missing something here, any help?

Comment: You are right and the book is wrong.

Comment: Yup and even simpler just look at the polynomial $p(x,y)=x$; then for all $y$, $p(0,y)=0$. You would need some form of positive definiteness condition on the top-degree coefficients, and presumably also assume the degree is even. But ok… a simpler (and true) statement is that for any complex polynomial $p(z)$ which is non-constant, we have $|p(z)|\to\infty$ as $|z|\to\infty$.